# "For what purpose is a knife a tool?" or "For what purpose is a tool a knife?"

Tags: questions, wh-questions

I tried to rephrase a sentence.

> A knife is a tool fo cutting.

But in a form of question...

And the expected answer is "It is for cutting".

Is it allowed to ask a question like that?

such as

**Choice A**

`For what purpose is a knife a tool?`

or

**Choice B**

`For what purpose is a tool a knife?`

I am not quite sure about that.

Comment: You can ask "What is a knife for?"

Comment: @WeatherVane "What is a knife as a tool for?" Is this uesd also?

Comment: No, but an alternative to the first, is "What is a knife *used* for?"